# Flatpickr time format manipulation

Tags: flatpickr

How do I get time picker in 12 hours and with leading zeroes for hours less than 10 ?
Current code;
`$('.time').flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    dateFormat: "h:i K",
});`

The output I get is 6:30 AM but I want to get 06:30 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Capital 'H'

$('.time').flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    noCalendar: true,
    dateFormat: "H:i K",
});

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. There's some issue while opting for 'PM' the time goes as 24 hr format. I will see for that.